# Accessing SQLite values from SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, sqlite, simplecursoradapter

I have a SQLite table called "Nodes" with a set of all nodes (each node has multiple properties).

In an activity, I use an extension of SimpleCursorAdapter to display a *subset* of the Nodes table, based on a SQL query, passing it the Cursor over the table of results (from the query).

```
{id_long, name_string, description_string, nodetype_enum_toString...}
    1, "home", "home_desc", "cool"
    2, "item1", "item1_desc", "warm"
    3, "item2", "item2_desc", "hot"
    4, "item3", "item3_desc", "warm"
    5, "item4", "item4_desc", "hot"
```

I want to modify each of the list items in my ListActivity such that it displays a different color based on whether an item is cool, warm or hot. I have a small (empty) view, but it's always defaulting to white (the 'else' portion).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    convertView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (convertView == null) convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.viewstack_item, null);
    View nodetype_view = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nodetype_view);

    mGenCursor_cur = mDataHelper_db.getAll();
    mGenCursor_cur.moveToPosition(position);

    Log.i("test", "node type key " + mGenCursor_cur.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.NODES_TYPE_KEY));
    String type_nt = mGenCursor_cur.getString(mGenCursor_cur.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.NODES_TYPE_KEY));
    String name_str = mGenCursor_cur.getString(mGenCursor_cur.getColumnIndex(DataHelper.NODES_NAME_KEY));
    Log.i("getView", title_str + "typeis " + type_nt + " at position " + position);

    if (prio_np.equals(NodePrio.HIGH.toString())) {
        Log.i("prio_np", "high red");
        prioView_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    } else if (prio_np.equals(NodePrio.NORMAL.toString())) {
        Log.i("prio_np", "norm magenta");
        prioView_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    } else {
        Log.i("prio_np", "else (low) white");
        prioView_view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    mGenCursor_cur.close();
    bindView(convertView, mContext, getCursor());
    return(convertView);
}
```

My issue is that while the cursor passed to the SimpleListAdapter will contain the _IDs (I assume) of the corresponding nodes in the subset I want, the *position* parameter in *getView* is local to the subset, so I can't cross-reference it with the Nodes table. Am I missing some easy technique?

### As always, any help appreciated.

comment 4 of the marked answer helped me solve this:
storing the cursor that was passed to the SimpleCursorAdapter as a member variable, then using move to position, and getLong:

```
mCursor_cur.moveToPosition(position);
long id = mCursor_cur.getLong(0);
```

where *position* is the local parameter in the getView() method, and 0 is used for getLong because the db_id is the first column in the cursor passed to the SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: don't know how I made that "as always bit" bold, but I'll leave it as it exemplifies my gratitude :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in java == should not be used for string comparison
`string1.equals(string2)` is what your are looking for
see [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html) for further info

Comment: Thanks I always got mixed between the two.

Comment: no sorry, the string comparison was the secondary part of the question which I would have tried anyway except that I was more distracted by the main part - getting a value from the row in the Nodes table, based on the cursor passed to SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: My mistake, I thought there was only one part. But for the first part, I remember that I kept the list ( your subset, but as a list ) as a member variable so that I could easily reference its position.